# 600 pixel wide page not appearing full on 640 pixel width mobile screen

Tags: html, ios, css, media-queries, responsive

I am testing a webpage on iPhone 5s (which has a resolution of 1136 x 640 pixels).

I have set meta as:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1, width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

and css:

```
body {
min-width: 600px;
}
```

The remaining classes on the page do not have pixel based width. They are all using % based width, none of which is more than 100%.

The page however, does not appear in full on phone's screen. I have to scroll **horizontally** to see complete view. 
Only when I set the body's min-width to 300px, the page appears full on phone's screen.

Now I am wondering why 600px cannot appear in full when phone support 640px horizontal resolution. I may be missing something very basic, please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing that you should count the point size of the iPhone screen, not the pixels.

[This website which lists the viewport for most devices](http://viewportsizes.com/?filter=iphone) confirms that.

Comment: I am reading about point size now on Google. However, can you suggest how should I specify min-width of the body to not go below 600 pixels (any other unit than pixel) so that my page appears on 600 pixel wide screen and scrolls on smaller ones?

Comment: Ohh! so the viewport is actually 320 pixels and not 640! Thanks a lot sir!

Comment: @PrashantGupta Indeed. Glad I could help.